# TypeScript Error with Generics in Custom Route Creation Function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

StackOverflow community,

I am working on a TypeScript project where I have created a custom function to define and create routes with associated types. However, I am encountering a type compatibility issue that I cannot resolve.

---

### Issue description

I have a `createRoutes` function and a `Route` class that works with different HTTP methods and response types. The issue arises when I try to use the `Route.Response` method in my route definitions. TypeScript throws an error indicating a type mismatch, but I'm not sure why this is happening.

### `Route` class implementation

```
import type { z } from 'zod';

export type HttpMethod = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PATCH' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';

export type Response<Data = unknown> = (data: Data) => RouteResponse<Data>;

interface RouteData<
  Method extends HttpMethod,
  Responses = Record<PropertyKey, Response>
> {
  Method: Method;
  Path: string;
  Headers?: z.ZodSchema;
  Query?: z.ZodSchema;
  Body?: Method extends 'GET' | 'DELETE' ? never : z.ZodSchema;
  Responses: Responses;
}

export class Route<
  Method extends HttpMethod,
  Responses extends Record<PropertyKey, Response> = Record<
    PropertyKey,
    Response
  >
> {
  public readonly Method: Method;
  public readonly Path: string;
  public readonly Headers?: z.ZodSchema;
  public readonly Query?: z.ZodSchema;
  public readonly Body?: Method extends 'GET' | 'DELETE' ? never : z.ZodSchema;
  public readonly Responses: Responses;

  constructor(private readonly data: RouteData<Method, Responses>) {
    this.Method = this.data.Method;
    this.Path = this.data.Path;
    this.Headers = this.data.Headers;
    this.Query = this.data.Query;
    this.Body = this.data.Body;
    this.Responses = this.data.Responses;
  }

  static Response<Data = unknown>() {
    return (data: Data, errors?: RouteResponseError[]) => {
      return new RouteResponse(data, errors);
    };
  }
}

export type GetRouteResponses<RouteType> = RouteType extends Route<
  infer _,
  infer Responses
>
  ? Responses
  : never;

export class RouteResponseError {
  constructor(
    public title: string,
    public message: string,
    public code?: string
  ) {}
}

export class RouteResponse<Data = unknown> {
  constructor(
    public data: Data,
    public errors?: RouteResponseError[],
    public success = !errors || errors.length === 0
  ) {}
}

export const createRoutes = <
  RoutesData extends Record<PropertyKey, RouteData<HttpMethod>>
>(
  routesData: RoutesData
) => {
  const routes = {} as Record<
    keyof RoutesData,
    Route<
      RoutesData[keyof RoutesData]['Method'],
      RoutesData[keyof RoutesData]['Responses']
    >
  >;

  for (const key in routesData) {
    routes[key] = new Route(routesData[key]);
  }

  return routes;
};
```

### `Route` class usage

```
const AuthRoutes = createRoutes({
  Init: {
    Method: 'POST',
    Path: '/auth/init',
    Body: AuthInitPasswordlessSchema,
    Responses: {
      Success: Route.Response<{ success: true }>(), // <= error is in this line
    },
  },
});
```

### Error message

```
Type '(data: { success: true; }, errors?: RouteResponseError[]) => RouteResponse<{ success: true; }>' is not assignable to type 'Response<unknown>'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ success: true; }'
```

### Attempts to Resolve

- I've verified the constructor of RouteResponse matches the expected types.
- I've checked the schema types for compatibility.

---

Could someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The simple yet less safe way of handling this is changing the default generic in your type Response to Data = any. That you're using the default value for the generic in creating both the RouteData type and in the class Route generic definition is where the problem begins. You need to find a way to infer and then include the actual response types and then patch those into when you're setting Response (sorry... this definitely isn't very clear... I can clarify further if that would help)

Comment: @G1N, yes, that's actually what I did for now, but the problem is that ESLint starts "yelling" when I use `any` type, and I have to add a comment to disable that rule (`// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`). I will stick with this "workaround" until something better comes to my mind, or someone can suggest a better solution. I would appreciate it if you help me with "`infer`ring" the type in the class itself (I don't know how to implement it). Thank you!